# GQL: I'm storing JSON in the DataStore. All json is getting converted to html entities, how to avoid this?

Tags: json, google-app-engine, gql, html-entities

The tittle says most:

I'm storing JSON in the DataStore. All json is getting converted to html entities, how can I avoid this?

Original I had

myJson = db.StringProperty()

it complained the json i had was to long and StringProperty had a limit of around 500 chars. Sugesting to use TextProperty instead.

It inserted without problems but now myJson looks like this when i fetch it from the database:

```
{ &quot;timeUnit&quot;: &quot;14&quot;, &quot;taskCounter&quot;: &quot;0&quot;, &quot;dependencyCounter&quot;: &quot;0&quot;, &quot;tasks&quot;: [], &quot;dependencies&quot;: []}
```

Any sugestions?

Edit:

## Code:

Model:

```
the_json = db.TextProperty()
```

Saving:

```
myObjectKey = request.POST["myKey"]
myJson = request.POST["myJson"]
element = myObject.get(myObjectkey)
logging.error(" -------------------------")
element.the_json = myJson
element.put()
```

Loading:

```
params = {}
myObjectKey = request.POST["myKey"]
element = myObject.get(myObjectKey)
params['the_json'] = myObject.the_json
return respond(request, "ajax/load.html",params) #this function is a redirect to shortcuts.render_to_response
```

For ajax I'm using jquery to handle everything. The JSON is a normal string with no '\n' in it.:

```
json_in_the_js = '{ "timeUnit": ...';
```

Comment: I know about protocol buffer and it's really nice, but I really need to be using json :) (just to avoid answers telling me to change to protocol buffer)

Comment: I replaced the names of the vars, if there is any small sintatic error it was due to translation has it was in portuguese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't in the datastore. It was in the fact that I was using a template to write the JSON in.

I generated the response by hand with:

```
response = HttpResponse(myObject.the_json)
```

And it worked great :)

Comment: ah...your template language was "auto escaping".  most template languages have way to turn that off at the block-level

Answer (score 3):

How are you fetching and displaying the JSON? This definitely isn't an issue with how it's stored in the datastore, but rather with how it's displayed, or possibly how it's being recieved. We need to be able to see all the code that handles it to tell which.